# Generate a complete Gaussian/normal distribution in C++ in the distributed order

Tags: c++, gaussian, normal-distribution

I'm trying to generate a Gaussian/normal distribution in C++. I already know the function

```
std::normal_distribution<> d{mean, std};
float number = d(gen);
```

However, I want to generate and use an ENTIRE distribution and not just one number extracted from the it.

That being said, I've been able to (for example) generate 500 samples - that's the length of the normal distribution I need. But I am at a loss as to how I can order the samples in a normal distribution order. Any ideas that I can think of, seem unnecessarily complicated and has be thinking that there HAS to be a simpler way to do this. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You can create your own [generator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UniformRandomBitGenerator) class which generates consecutive numbers from 0 to 1 with a specific step size.

Comment: Do you mean you want bigger numbers near the mean and smaller numbers near the edges, so you can plot a normal distribution graph?  Then you will have to create a histogram of generated values (and possibly) normalize the values and plot that

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes more or less. I do want bigger numbers near the mean and smaller numbers near the edges, but I don't want to plot them. I need the values themselves.

Comment: `std::random` library is used to generate pseudo-random numbers matching the given distribution. To create a probability density function, you should get the formula from Wikipedia or other source and just plug in values in preset intervals.

Comment: Like this? https://onlinegdb.com/c6fKpSKQk (ok with plot, but it is the histogram that counts, pun intended)

Comment: You're probably looking for the normal distribution in here: [Boost Statistical Distributions and Functions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/math/doc/html/dist.html)

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question that you want to use the normal distribution formula itself as a function, not just as a helper to generate normal distributed samples. This is not directly available from the C++11 random generation components of the standard library.

Therefore, if boost is an option, you can use the following code which is based on the statistical distributions and functions package:

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/normal.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double mean = 0.0;
    double sigma = 1.0;

    boost::math::normal dist(mean, sigma);

    double a =-10.0;
    double b =10.0;
    int N=1000;
    double h = (b-a)/(N-1);

    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        double x = a+i*h;
        std::cout<<x<<"    "<<boost::math::pdf(dist, x)<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73adf57090211348)

Otherwise, if you need a histogram, consider the comment by @PepijnKramer. But frankly, why should you want the histogram from a known distribution? (a histogram basically works the other way round, to get you an idea of an unknown distribution)